# I don't know how to get the long number on the left

Tags: matlab

Write a script that produces the below output. It should iterate from 0 to 9 to produce expressions on the left, perform the specified operation to get the results on the right, and print exactly in the format shown here

1 x 8 + 1 = 9

12 x 8 + 2 = 98

123 x 8 + 3 = 987

1234 x 8 + 4 = 9876

12345 x 8 + 5 = 98765

123456 x 8 + 6 = 987654

1234567 x 8 + 7 = 9876543

12345678 x 8 + 8 = 98765432

123456789 x 8 + 9 = 987654321

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! I'd advise for next time try to post a code attempt. The community is a lot more helpful when that happens. You may also like to look into minimal reproducible examples.

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "I don't know how to get the long number on the left"?
If the script generate the number to be printed out you should also be able to retrieve it for you other pourposes.
Moreover, which scripting language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

here's a way playing with strings and number conversions

```
x=[];
for i=1:8
    x=[x num2str(i)]
    number(i)=str2num(x);
end

number(:)

ans =

       1
      12
     123
    1234
   12345
  123456
 1234567
12345678
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the format `a*b+c = Result` the following equations can be printed by generating the values in a loop. The loop runs from 1 to 9. Variable `a` holds the first term and concatenates the variable `Expression_Index` to itself upon every iteration. Variable `b` is the constant 8. Variable `c` only holds the current `Expression_Index`. Variables `a,b and c` are strings that can be easily concatenated using the `+` operator. The variable `Result` is an integer since it requires no concatenation to occur. The function `str2num` allows for the conversion from strings to numbers that can be used in calculating the `Result`. Finally the `fprintf()` function prints out strings denoted by the `%s` placeholders and integers denoted by the `%d` placeholder.

**Equation Format: a × b + c = Result**

### Iterative Script:

```
clear;
clc;

a = "";
b = "8";

for Expression_Index = 1:9

a = a + num2str(Expression_Index);
c = num2str(Expression_Index);

Result = str2num(a)*str2num(b) + str2num(c);


fprintf("%s x %s + %s = %d\n",a,b,c,Result);

end
```

### Result:

[image: Result]